# How can you improve the uniform distribution of a given random function?

Tags: linux, bash, function, random, random-seed

The question is related on Linux like Debian, bash and a given function which use RANDOM.

Every improvement should use bash only.

Given are the follow function:

```
getRND(){
    min="${1:-1}"   ## min is the first parameter, or 1 if no parameter is given           
    max="${2:-100}" ## max is the second parameter, or 100 if no parameter is given
    rnd_count=$((RANDOM%(max-min+1)+min));
    echo "$rnd_count"
}

var=$(getRND -10 10) # Call the function
echo $var # output
```

How too:

- Improve the randomness

The solution is sought for Linux systems on which no bash 5.1 is installed already and therefore no SRANDOM can be used up to now.

Comment: ```RANDOM=$(date +%s)``` ?

Comment: when you evaluate *statement* as ```$(statement)``` it get evaluated in a subshell with its own random seed and and corresponding pseudorandom sequence. so I suggest you to get random value in main shell and pass it into function for normalization.

Comment: Your question reflects a conceptual error about PRNGs and seeds.  All PRNGs are algorithms to advance from one state to the next, and since the number of bits involved is finite, eventually you'll repeat a state and then it's all repetition, all the time.  In other words, all PRNG sequences can be viewed as big cycles.  The seed is used to set the initial state, i.e., all it does is choose your entry point to the cycle.  No seed makes the PRNG "more random" than any other seed. The mimicry of randomness is built into the state transition algorithm, it doesn't depend on the seed.

Comment: You still have the same problem.  You talk about seeding, and then ask "How to improve the randomness of the fuction above, if possible?"  Quality of the randomness is a characteristic of the algorithm being used, it has nothing to do with the seed.  If you want better randomness, don't use bash's `RANDOM`.  For example, you could run `python3 -c 'import random; print(random.randint(-10,10))'` or `ruby -e 'puts rand(-10..10)'` within your shell script.  If you restrict yourself to bash's `RANDOM`, that's what determines/limits the quality of your results.

Comment: `no Terminal 5.1` -> no __bash__ 5.1

Comment: `Every improvement should use bash only.` Is this for toy or research purposes only? Why constrain yourself to only bash?

Comment: What, specifically, do you mean when you say you'd like "a more random random"?  As things stand, your question is ill-defined.

Comment: Please don't vandalize your own posts. When you post here, you give SO the right to distribute the content under CC-by SA 4.0. Any vandalism will be reverted.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> what can be improved on a given random function to make it more random or for a bigger range or something else?
>
> and therefore no SRANDOM can be used up to now.
>
> How to improve the randomness of the fuction above, if possible ?

Sooo write your own SRANDOM with your own semantics. Ex:

```
srandom() {
   # take random number from /dev/urandom
   # we take only just 4 bytes - one 2^32 number
   printf "%d\n" "0x$(
       dd if=/dev/urandom of=/dev/stdout bs=4 count=1 status=none |
       xxd -p)"
}
```

and then:

```
normalize_value(){
   ...
   rnd=$(srandom)
   rnd_count=$((rnd / ...))
}
```

> Accepting a wider range of numbers

If you are not happy with the way shell arithmetic expansion works, then... use a different tool. `bc` calculator has unlimited range.

```
rnd_count=$(echo "
     # see https://superuser.com/questions/31445/gnu-bc-modulo-with-scale-other-than-0
     scale=0; 
     # super big random number from three 2^32 numbers
     rnd = $(srandom) * 2^(32*2) +  $(srandom) * 2^32 + $(srandom)
     rnd % ($max - $min + 1) + $min
     " | bc)
```

You can write your own C program with `getrandom()` and compile it on the fly `echo "int main() { stuff(); }" | gcc -xc - && ./a.out; rm ./a.out` basically granting you any semantics you want. There are also other scripting languages, like perl, python, ruby, all most probably with their own big-number libraries and urandom number generation implementations. Sky the limit.

> Every improvement should use bash only.

Is from my perspective a pointless limitation - overall, I am paid for results, not really "how" I solve problems. Anyway, you could, giving you a bunch of ideas how to proceed:

- First write a function that would read from `/dev/urandom` and convert the bytes into a number.

  - I have no good idea how to do it in pure bash while keeping the randomness at sane levels. I suspect the input will drain fast.
  - You could read one byte from urandom. You'll have to ignore `read` exit status, cause the byte may be zero byte or newline.
  - Then check if that byte is a digit. If it's not, repeat previous step.
  - Treat such algorithm treat as a generator of random number within the range of 0-9. Build bigger numbers from those digits.
- Then develop your own big-number library using arithmetic expansion as a "backend", written in bash.

  - Seems pretty pointless, because `bc` is commonly available.
  - This would work as usual big number libraries do.
  - I suggest to store the number as an array of number at max 2^16. For inspiration, research similar libraries written in C and C++ languages, and convert it to bash.

Comment: @ KamilCuk, Can you show me the full code of how to use this please. I am not programmer enough to understand this: normalize_value(){
   ...
   rnd=$(srandom)
   rnd_count=$((rnd / ...))
}

Comment: https://repl.it/@kamilcukrowski/FatherlyEuphoricServers#main.sh

Answer (score 1):

making seed for RANDOM in main shell and expecting it to be favoured in subshell is pointless because new shell makes its own initialization of seed.

so you need to seed and use RANDOM of main shell and pass value into another function for transformation.

here is an example how to make your seed to work:

```sh
#!/bin/bash


normalize_value(){
    value_to_normalize=$1
    min="${2:-1}"   ## min is the first parameter, or 1 if no parameter is given           
    max="${3:-100}" ## max is the second parameter, or 100 if no parameter is given
    rnd_count=$((value_to_normalize % (max-min+1)+min));
    echo "$rnd_count"
}

RANDOM=$(date +%s%N | cut -b10-19)

rnd=$RANDOM # get random value in a context of main shell and your seed
var=$(normalize_value $rnd -10 10) # pass random value into normalizer function
echo $var # output

###### following example will NOT WORK because statement refers to subshell's random generator
RANDOM=1
var=$(normalize_value $RANDOM -10 10) # wrong random sequence is used (not seeded by you)
echo $var # output

var=$(normalize_value $RANDOM -10 10) # wrong
echo $var # output
```

Answer (score -1):

And this is how it looks when the code from the question and the code from KamilCuk's answer are combined in one function for doing the random more equally distributed:

```
#!/bin/bash

get_rnd_num_eq_dis(){
    min="${1:-1}"   # min is the first parameter, or 1 if no parameter is given           
    max="${2:-100}" # max is the second parameter, or 100 if no parameter is given
#   rnd=$(srandom)
    srnd="$((0x$(dd if=/dev/urandom of=/dev/stdout bs=4 count=1 status=none | xxd -p)))"
    rnd_count=$((srnd%(max-min+1)+min));
    echo "$rnd_count"
}

var=$(get_rnd_num_eq_dis -100 100) # Call the function
echo "$var" # output

sleep 2
```

Remark: Its looks like it can be used in a range bigger than +-32000