# Why is generating a higher amount of random data much slower?

Tags: bash, random, pipe, brace-expansion

I want to generate a high amount of random numbers. I wrote the following bash command (note that I am using `cat` here for demonstrational purposes; in my real use case, I am piping the numbers into a process):

```
for i in {1..99999999}; do echo -e "$(cat /dev/urandom | tr -dc '0-9' | fold -w 5 | head -n 1)"; done | cat
```

The numbers are printed at a very low rate. However, if I generate a smaller amount, it is much faster:

```
for i in {1..9999}; do echo -e "$(cat /dev/urandom | tr -dc '0-9' | fold -w 5 | head -n 1)"; done | cat
```

Note that the only difference is `9999` instead of `99999999`.

Why is this? Is the data buffered somewhere? Is there a way to optimize this, so that the random numbers are piped/streamed into `cat` immediately?

Comment: Are you sure the rate is slower, or do you just mean it took longer to generate more random numbers?

Comment: "_When  read,  the  `/dev/urandom` device returns random bytes using a pseudorandom number generator seeded from the entropy pool.  Reads from this device do not block (i.e., the CPU is not yielded), but can incur an appreciable delay when requesting large amounts of data._"

Comment: I suggest to replace `echo -e "$(cat /dev/urandom | tr -dc '0-9' | fold -w 5 | head -n 1)"` with `r=$RANDOM$RANDOM$RANDOM$RANDOM$RANDOM; echo ${r:0:5}`

Comment: The question you need to ask yourself, is _what do you need the random numbers for_? Is it for a toy project or some use-case where everyone is friendly and it doesn't matter if someone guesses the random numbers? Or is it some adversarial context, e.g. related to security / cryptography or games people play for money or such?

Comment: In this case, it is just random data to have some data, anything is good. It does not have to cryptographically secure.

Comment: This should be faster: `tr -dc '0-9' </dev/urandom | fold -w 5 | head -n 9999 | cat`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Why is this?

Generating `{1..99999999}` 100000000 arguments and then parsing them requires a lot of memory allocation from bash. This significantly stalls the whole system.

Additionally, large chunks of data are read from `/dev/urandom`, and about 96% of that data are filtered out by `tr -dc '0-9'`. This significantly depletes the entropy pool and additionally stalls the whole system.

> Is the data buffered somewhere?

Each process has its own buffer, so:

- `cat /dev/urandom` is buffering
- `tr -dc '0-9'` is buffering
- `fold -w 5` is buffering
- `head -n 1` is buffering
- the left side of pipeline - the shell, has its own buffer
- and the right side - `| cat` has its own buffer

That's 6 buffering places. Even ignoring input buffering from `head -n1` and from the right side of the pipeline `| cat`, that's 4 output buffers.

Also, save animals and [stop cat abuse](http://porkmail.org/era/unix/award.html). Use `tr </dev/urandom`, instead of `cat /dev/urandom | tr`. Fun fact - `tr` can't take filename as a argument.

> Is there a way to optimize this, so that the random numbers are piped/streamed into cat immediately?

Remove the whole code.

Take only as little bytes from the random source as you need. To generate a 32-bit number you only need 32 bits - **no more**. To generate a 5-digit number, you only need 17 bits  - rounding to 8-bit bytes, that's only 3 bytes. The `tr -dc '0-9'` is a cool trick, but it definitely shouldn't be used in any real code.

Strangely [recently I answered I guess a similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66350341/what-can-be-improved-on-a-given-random-function-to-make-it-more-equally-distribu/66368271#66368271), copying the code from there, you could:

```
for ((i=0;i<100000000;++i)); do echo "$((0x$(dd if=/dev/urandom of=/dev/stdout bs=4 count=1 status=none | xxd -p)))"; done | cut -c-5
# cut to take first 5 digits
```

But that still would be **unacceptably** slow, as it runs 2 processes for each random number (and I think just taking the first 5 digits will have a bad distribution).

I suggest to use `$RANDOM`, available in bash. If not, use `$SRANDOM` if you **really want** `/dev/urandom` (and really know why you want it). If not, I suggest to write the random number generation from `/dev/urandom` in a real programming language, like C, C++, python, perl, ruby. I believe one could write it in `awk`.

The following looks nice, but still converting binary data to hex, just to convert them to decimal later is a workaround for that shell just can't work with binary data:

```
count=10;
# take count*4 bytes from input
dd if=/dev/urandom of=/dev/stdout bs=4 count=$count status=none |
# Convert bytes to hex 4 bytes at a time
xxd -p -c 4 |
# Convert hex to decimal using GNU awk
awk --non-decimal-data '{printf "%d\n", "0x"$0}'
```

Comment: `/dev/urandom` shouldn't care about "depleting the pool", though at least the Linux implementation is slower than many other CSPRNGs (unless it's changed recently). 5 decimal digits is 5*ln(10)/ln(2) ~= 16.5 bits worth, so 17 bits is can represent anything < 99999 (2^17 is 131072). But of course the distribution is abysmal if you just take the last 5 digits without regard for if the number is > 99999. But any change from N bits to M-digit decimal numbers gives a skewed result if you don't account for the ranges not matching.

Answer (score 1):

Why are you running this in a loop?  You can just run a single set of these commands to generate everything, e.g.:

```
cat /dev/urandom | tr -dc '0-9' | fold -w 5 | head -n 100000000
```

I.e. just generate a single stream of numbers, rather than generate them individually.

I'd second the suggestion of using another language for this, it should be much more efficient.  For example, in Python it would just be:

```py
from random import randrange
for _ in range(100000000):
    print(randrange(100000))
```

Answer (score 1):

@SamMason gave the best [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66430700/14552476) so far, as he completely did away with the loop:

> `cat /dev/urandom | tr -dc '0-9' | fold -w 5 | head -n 100000000`

That still leaves a lot of room for improvement though. First, `tr -dc '0-9'` only uses about 4% of the stuff that's coming out of /dev/urandom :-)  Second, depending on how those random numbers will be consumed in the end, some additional overhead may be incurred for getting rid of leading zeros -- so that some numbers will not be interpreted as octal.  Let me suggest a better alternative, using the `od` command:

```
outputFile=/dev/null  # For test. Replace with the real file.
count=100000000

od -An  -t u2  -w2  /dev/urandom | head -n $count >$outputFile
```

A qick test with the `time` command showed this to be roughly four times faster than the `tr` version.  And there is really no need for using "another language", as both `od` and `head` are highly optimized, and this whole thing runs at native speed.

***NOTE:*** The above command will be generating 16-bit integers, ranging from 0 to 65535 inclusive. If you need a larger range, then you could go for 32 bit numbers, and that will give you a range from 0 to 4294967295:

```
od -An  -t u4  -w4  /dev/urandom | head -n $count >$outputFile
```

If needed, the end user can scale those down to the desired size with a modulo division.